# Apply *ngFor on object having two arrays with objects, Angular2

Tags: angular, ngfor

This is the data object in abc.component.ts
(user[] is getting filled by objects after http request)

```
data = {
    users: [],
    photos: []
};
```

The template file is abc.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="#d of data"  class="media">
<div class="media-left media-middle">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="media-object" height="64px" width="64px" src="#" alt="img">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">{{ d.users.name }}</h4>
    ...
</div>
```

The snapshot of the data object in console.log is

[image: data object]

When I try to display the name property in users, i get the error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
```

How can I correct the for loop?

Comment: share your component code here which throws the error.

Comment: component code
`export class HttpTestComponent implements OnInit{

    data = {
        users: [],
        photos: []
    };

    users = [];

    constructor(private _httpTestService: HttpTestService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._httpTestService.getPosts()
            .subscribe(res =>{this.data.users = res});
    console.log(this.data);
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You have just one object - one variable - `data`. It is not possible to iterate via ***ngFor** like that. You could make a loop for `users[]` or `photos[]` arrays separately.

For example, it should works properly:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of data.users"  class="media">
<div class="media-left media-middle">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="media-object" height="64px" width="64px" src="#" alt="img">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">{{ user.name }}</h4>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to display the user name with `{{ d.users.name }}` you are trying to access the name property of the array users which obviusly does not have. You have to do `{{ d.users[0]].name }}` or loop over the users array instead of the `data` object.